# List(of String) in structure in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, list, structure

How would I make use of a List(of String) in a structure in vb.net. for example

```
Structure examplestrut
    Public exampleslist As List(Of String)
End Structure
```

How would I call exampleslist.add("example 1")?

Comment: In .Net, you should prefer Class over Structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
Dim myStruct as ExampleStruct
myStruct.exampleList = new List(Of String)()
myStruct.exampleList.Add("Hi there!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Its also worth mentioning that if you already have a 'myStruct' declared earlier in the program and you need to empty it, you use

```
    myStruct.exampleList = new List(Of String)()
```

rather than

```
    myStruct.exampleList.Clear()
```